# Universal law of gravitation - order of operations

Tags: javascript, simulation, physics, verlet-integration

I'm working on a little N-Body Simulation in JavaScript. It's running as I expected, but I noticed something odd. The simulation uses a verlet integrator and the function that accumulates the forces has the line:

`force.length = (this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass) / dist * dist;`

As I said, the simulation works as expected, but shouldn't the code actually read:

`force.length = (this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass) / (dist * dist)`;

where the order of operations is correct for the square of the distance? When I have it that way the simulation blows up. Kind of an odd thing, the wrong way works correctly, or seems to. Anyone have an idea of what the issue is? Complete code and running example here:

https://gist.github.com/arctwelve/ca5868f80d0b0cd5791e
http://bl.ocks.org/arctwelve/ca5868f80d0b0cd5791e

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "blows up"?

Comment: @Bergi "blowing up' is a term used in physics simulation and refers to numeric instability. Usually the thing being simulated appears to quickly lose stability and 'blow up'. In my case I'm using it more generally, in the sense that it's not working at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `var dist = vect.x * vect.x + vect.y * vect.y;` is actually setting `dist` to *the square of the distance*, so `force.length = (this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass) / dist;` should give you the correct result.

Comment: Yes! That appears to be it. It's the equivalent of getting the true distance `var dist = Math.sqrt(vect.x * vect.x + vect.y * vect.y);` and then getting its square `force.length = this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass / Math.pow(dist, 2);` Interesting, as @Pointy mentioned, my original code negates the distance. The sim still works but the force is a constant, not relative to the distance of the bodies.

Comment: Yes. You don't really need the true distance in this case, so it's more efficient just to compute its square. So, how about accepting my answer? :-)

Comment: Sorry, I had to run off to my job at NASA with the corrected algorithm before I could mark your answer correct :)

Comment: I hope the rocket launched on time.

Comment: This was actually for the vending machine.

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation of

```
force.length = (this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass) / dist * dist;
```

is

```
force.length = ((this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass) / dist) * dist;
```

The division operator and the multiplication operator have the same operator precedence, and they group left-to-right. Thus your expression is effectively

```
force.length = this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass;
```

I think perhaps your expectations of how the simulation should work may be off.

Comment: 'I think perhaps your expectations of how the simulation should work may be off.' Heh, yes, well my expectation is that I'm simulating the universal law of gravitation. As you point out the distance is not a factor in the equation, so that's a pretty good sign I'm doing something wrong. The odd thing is that the simulation does seem (in watching it run) to take into account the distance of bodies. The angle of the force vector does implicitly contain some length information `force.angle = pb.curr.subtract(pa.curr);  force.length = this.gravity * pa.mass * pb.mass`

Comment: ...actually, there's no length or distance added to the force. the force is just a constant of gravity * mass. It yields some interesting results, but is probably not a true n-body sim.